# CSS Transitions on Touch Devices Doesn't Revert to Normal State

Tags: css, touch, css-transitions, transition

I've got some buttons that have a CSS transition from black to yellow on hover, then return back to black. When clicked they make an AJAX call. They work nicely when I hover over them and click a mouse on all desktop browsers (naturally IE9 and lower ignore it), but on both iOS Safari, and the standard Android browser, the transition stays yellow after I have clicked the button. They do not return to the normal black state, like they do on a desktop system.

Any clues as to where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated. For those with a touch device, this Fiddle demonstrates the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/wpyz9whn/1/

CSS

```
a.button {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 0.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.8s ease-out;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
a.button:hover {
    background: #ffcc00;
    color: #000;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in;
}
a.button:active {
    background: #ff9c00;
    transition: background 0s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background 0s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background 0s ease-in;
}
a.button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="button" onclick="return addToBasket(11628937,'/')">Add to Basket</a>
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?